# When I open my project all shadows have gone

Tags: lighting, shadows

I am using blender 2.9 am creating a room with chocofur model manager for furniture, etc, it looked nice with all the shadows and lighting but I have saved it every step of the way, but now when I open it all shadows have gone and nothing happens when I try to add the process again. I have watched tutorial again and again and everything is right.

Comment: Any chance you are in material preview mode, and not rendered preview? To be sure, press Z in  the 3D viewport and select "rendered" from the pie menu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, sorry.

In addition to Christopher Bennet's comment (making sure you are in the rendered viewport, Z -> Rendered) I will suggest another possible cause for future readers.

In Eevee, one can turn off shadows manually for each light source. You can click on a light source in the outliner, go to object data properties (the light bulb). There you can select two checkboxes: Shadow and Contact shadows. Check if these have not been accidentally turned off.